# Get nodeValue of PHP DOMDocumentFragment?

Tags: php, domdocument

Can anyone please tell me how do I get the nodeValue of any PHP DOMDocumentFragment? Or Is it possible converting this object into the node so I can get the value?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself. Actually, **DOMDocumentFragment** is always on top of the elements we created inside. So this is how it can be accessed.

```
$newFragment->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue
```